# I get a segmentation fault when I create a node with a struct in c++

Tags: c++, class, struct

I use the following struct as a node of a heap

```
struct Node
{
   int k;
}*p,**array;
```

and I create a class which is the heap. In my code i have to initialize the heap in a function and I do the folloowing

```
for (int i= 0; i < V;i++)
{
    array[i] = newNode(0);
}
```

where the function newNode() is the following :

```
struct Node* newNode(int k)
{
   struct Node* node;
   node->k = k;
   return node;
}
```

The problem is that when i debug my code it crashes with a segmentation fault in the function newNode() , the line is :

```
node->k = k;
```

Ireally don't know what to do :(

Comment: C++ has constructors for initializing objects upon creation. Thus, you don't really need `newNode` after all. Nevertheless, in `newNode()` you don't allocate `node`.

Comment: @101010 so should i erase the function newNode and initialize like that: array[i]=0;

Comment: IMHO yes you should.

Comment: `struct Node* node;` Here you declare a pointer to a Node, _but_ you don't make it point to anything.
   `node->k = k;` Here you dereference that pointer, causing _undefined behavior_, because it didn't point to any valid Node object.

Comment: Don't use a variable's value until you assign it one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `newNode` function, you haven't initialized the `node` you declared. That pointer to a node therefore wasn't properly allocated. To fix this, you have to use `new` operator.

```
struct Node* newNode(int k)
{
   struct Node* node = new Node();
   node->k = k;
   return node;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `node` uninitialized. It doesn't point anywhere, but you're dereferencing it (`node->`). This causes undefined behavior in C++, of which a segfault is a valid form.

If this is C++ as you say, stop writing it as C and start writing it as C++.

I.e.

- No need for manually managing owning pointers.
- No need for pointers in this simple code at all. Also, they just slow things down. Avoid them whenever possible even in C.
- Use C++ standard library containers instead of manually allocated arrays.
- Write constructors instead of making functions like `newSomething`.
- Use constructors for objects instead of manually assigning their fields.

This way, your code becomes more readable, easier to manage, and less error prone.

With these changes, your code could look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> // To be able to use std::vector

struct Node
{
   Node(int param = 0) : k(param) {} // Constructor that takes an int and uses it to initialize k. If you don't provide the parameter, it defaults to 0 automatically ("= 0").
   int k;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Node> nodeArray(4); // Initialize the vector to hold 4 default constructed Nodes.

    Node anotherNode(42); // Instantiate a new Node object with k set to 42.
    nodeArray.push_back(anotherNode); // Copy it to the back of the vector.

    for (auto& node : nodeArray) // Loops through all elements in nodeArray.
        std::cout << node.k << ','; // Print the value of k of the current element.
}
```

The above prints `0,0,0,0,42,`.

For more info on how to use a `std::vector`, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).